# ¿Cómo guardar en un archivo los elementos de un lista que pertenece a una clase en C#?

Tags: c#

Actualmente estoy estudiando C# en la universidad y se nos pidió hacer un pequeño programa en consola. El programa consta de tres clases:

1. Main
2. Entry
3. Journal

La clase Entry, escribí lo siguiente:

```
public class Entry
{
    public string _date = "";
    public string _prompt = "";
    public string _userInput = "";
    public void Display()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Date: {_date} - Prompt: {_prompt}\n{_userInput}");
    }
}
```

La clase Journal almacena una lista de objetos de tipo Entry:

```
public class Journal
{
    public List<Entry> _entries = new List<Entry>();

    public void AddEntry(Entry e)
    {
        _entries.Add(e);
    }

    public void Display()
    {   
        foreach (Entry e in _entries)
        {
            e.Display();
            Console.WriteLine();   
        } 
    }
}
```

Además se me pide que agrege un método llamado SaveFile en la clase Journal, yo intente lo siguiente:

```
public void SaveFile()
{
    Console.WriteLine("What is the filename?");
    string fileName = Console.ReadLine();

    using (StreamWriter outputFile = new StreamWriter(fileName))
    { 
        foreach(Entry e in _entries)
        {
            outputFile.WriteLine(e);
        } 
    }
}
```

La clase Main me permite mostrar los elementos de la lista que voy añadiendo a la clase Journal, el método SaveFile funciona pero no me da el resultado esperado, guardo el archivo con extensión .txt. Supongamos que guardo dos elementos en la lista, pero cuando posteriormente abro el archivo con extensión .txt me aparecen así:

```
Entry 
Entry
```

Espero mi consulta sea clara, es mi primer publicación.

Les agradecería mucho su ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

No mostraste la clase `Entry` pero me imagino que no debes haber sobreescrito la función [`ToString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.tostring) de dicha clase.

Si prestas atención, se está llamando a la sobrecarga con un parámetro tipo `object` de la función [`WriteLine`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.textwriter.writeline#system-io-textwriter-writeline(system-object)). Lo que hace es llamar a la función `ToString` del objeto e imprimir el resultado.

Por simplicidad, puedes hacer que imprima cada uno de los miembros relevantes separados por comas. Puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```
class Entry {
    int miembro1;
    string miembro2;
    
    int miembroIrrelevante;

    public override string ToString(){
        return miembro1 + ", " + miembro2;
    }
}
```

Nota que para sobreescribir métodos se hace mediante la palabra clave [`override`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/override).

---

A modo de comentario, una solución más sofisticada es la [serialización](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/serialization/).

Answer (score 0):

Tengo entendido que deseas guardar en tu archivo `txt` esta cadena `$"Date: {_date} - Prompt: {_prompt}\n{_userInput}"` por cada iteración de tu lista de `Entry`.

Como pareces ser nuevo en C#, me gustaría orientarte un poco:

En C# existe una clase base para todos los tipos, es la clase `System.Object` y esta, a su vez, contiene un método `ToString` que devuelve una cadena cuyo contenido es la combinación del espacio de nombres + el nombre del objeto.

Es decir, que cada tipo instanciable, **no** marcado como estático, que uses en el lenguaje, expondrá un método `ToString` que puedes invocar de forma explícita:

```
Console.WriteLine(entry.ToString());
```

O de forma implícita, esto es, dejando que el compilador lo llame por vos:

```
Console.WriteLine(entry);
Console.WriteLine(entry + "");
```

Y es que si concatenas un tipo con una cadena o empleas una función de impresión como es `WriteLine` entonces se llama a `ToString` y se usa lo que este devuelve.

---

Tu clase `Entry` presenta el método `ToString` y este, por defecto, devuelve el nombre del tipo `Entry`, que es lo que se escribe en tu archivo.

En C#, puedes usar la palabra reservada `override` para sobreescribir métodos provenientes de clases base. Es decir, de ahora mismo de forma implícita, tu clase `Entry` es algo así:

```
public class Entry : System.Object
{
}
```

Y quieres sobreescribir el método `ToString` proveniente de `System.Object`, esto lo puedes hacer de la siguiente forma:

```
public class Entry : System.Object
{
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "Aquí devuelves la cadena que se escribirá en tu archivo";
    }
}
```

---

Acá te dejo un ejemplo probado en C#10:

```
List<Entry> _entries = new List<Entry>
{
    new Entry { _date = DateTime.Now.ToString(), _prompt = "Test 1", _userInput = "Input 1" },
    new Entry { _date = DateTime.Now.ToString(), _prompt = "Test 2", _userInput = "Input 2" },
    new Entry { _date = DateTime.Now.ToString(), _prompt = "Test 3", _userInput = "Input 3" }
};

// Escribimos en el archivo
Console.WriteLine("What is the filename?");
string fileName = Console.ReadLine();

using (StreamWriter outputFile = new StreamWriter(fileName))
{ 
    foreach(Entry e in _entries)
    {
        outputFile.WriteLine(e);
    } 
}

public class Entry
{
    public string _date = "";
    public string _prompt = "";
    public string _userInput = "";

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"Date: {_date} - Prompt: {_prompt}\n{_userInput}";
    }
}
```

Si no tienes acceso a esta versión, puedes dejar un comentario a esta respuesta y la actualizaré.

Comment: Ok me expresé mal. Sí hay tipos estáticos y no estáticos. Que un tipo (clase o struct) sea estático significa que no puede instanciarse. Una clase no estática también puede tener campos estáticos. En definitiva, quizá quisiste decir ***cada instancia*** y no ***cada tipo no estático***. Espero que ahora quede más claro.

Comment: @Mateo Ahora he entendido tu punto. Eliminé mis comentarios y edité mi respuesta para aplicar tu sugerencia. Además te doy +1 en agradecimiento por señalarme este detalle que podría generar confusión. Gracias.